# Ubuntu 16.04 fails to install python3.5.2

Tags: python3

Ubuntu 16.04 comes with python2.7.12. I have removed it and tried to install python 3.5.2 but apt-get install  fails complaining that I need to autoremove many libraries. Is python 3.5.2 supported in Ubuntu 16.04?
If so, what do I need to do to install it?

Comment: Yes, Python 3.5.2 is supported and already installed in Ubuntu 16.04, which you just broke horribly by uninstalling a critical part of :(

Comment: @Don When you were uninstalling Python 2, `apt-get` gave you a long list of packages that it would uninstall and you said yes to all of that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you cannot remove python2.7. Many applications in Ubuntu rely on it to work. Without it, Ubuntu cannot run properly.

You may want to copy the python2.7 related binaries back to where they should be. But this can be a very tricky thing to do, because you need know what to copy first.

So, maybe the easiest solution is to reinstall your OS.

As to how to find python3.5.2, you just need to call `python3` instead of `python`.
If you run `python3 --version` in a newly installed Ubuntu 16.04, you will find it is 3.5.2 already.